# Js/Jquery how to remove previous image thumbnail when choose another image?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing an upload function that will allow the user to upload a chosen image to the server, and it is supposed to show a thumbnail of the current image. But when another image is chosen, it will add in the newer image thumbnail, and wouldn't remove the older image thumbnail.

So, how do I remove the previous image thumbnail and replace it with the newer one?

Here is my javascript code:

```
    function previewFiles() {
        var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
        var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

        function readAndPreview(file) {

            // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
            if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.height = 200;
                    image.title = file.name;
                    image.style.marginTop = '10px';
                    image.style.marginRight = '10px';
                    image.style.borderRadius = '3px';
                    image.style.marginBottom = '220px';
                    image.src = this.result;
                    preview.appendChild(image);

                }, false);
                
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        }

        if (files) {
            [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
        }

    }
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="browse" accept='.jpeg, .png, .jpg' onchange='previewFiles()' name="image" />
<div id='preview'></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using the FileReader, use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the children before adding new one.

```
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.height = 200;
                    image.title = file.name;
                    image.style.marginTop = '10px';
                    image.style.marginRight = '10px';
                    image.style.borderRadius = '3px';
                    image.style.marginBottom = '220px';
                    image.src = this.result;
                    
                    //removes all children (images)
                    preview.childNodes.forEach(c => preview.removeChild(c));
                    
                    preview.appendChild(image);
```